# Link annotations on type parameters in subtypes to declaring type parameters in supertype

Tags: java, generics, reflection, annotations, java-8

Let there be a type extending `java.util.Map`:

```
public interface IdentifiableMap<ID, KEY, VALUE> extends Map<KEY, VALUE>{

    ID getId();
}
```

Also let there be a field of that type which declares an annotation on one of the type parameters (as it's possible as of Java 8):

```
private IdentifiableMap<String, @Size(min=1) String, Integer> myMap = ...;
```

Using the Java reflection API, how can I find out from this declaration which annotations have been given for the type parameters from the `Map` interface? In other words, I'd like to deduct that the `@Size` annotation has been given for the `K` type parameter of `java.util.Map`.

I know how to obtain the annotations for the type parameters from the field's `AnnotatedParameterizedType`, but I'm missing how to correlate this to the type parameters of the super type `Map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is far away from being easy. The following code assumes that you want to lookup the annotations for a type that is *directly* implementing or extending the type, otherwise the code would become even more complicated or get ambiguity problems for interfaces indirectly implemented multiple times.

```
static Annotation[][] getActualAnnotations(AnnotatedType at, Class<?> target) {
    Type[] typeParameters = target.getTypeParameters();
    if(typeParameters.length==0) return new Annotation[0][];
    Type t=at.getType();
    Map<Type,Annotation[]> atArgAnnos;
    Class<?> raw;
    if(t instanceof Class) {
        atArgAnnos=Collections.emptyMap();
        raw=(Class<?>)t;
        if(raw==target) return new Annotation[typeParameters.length][0];
    }
    else if(t instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        ParameterizedType pt=(ParameterizedType)t;
        raw=(Class<?>)pt.getRawType();
        Type[] param=raw.getTypeParameters();
        Annotation[][] a = Arrays
            .stream(((AnnotatedParameterizedType)at).getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments())
            .map(AnnotatedType::getAnnotations)
            .toArray(Annotation[][]::new);
        if(raw==target) return a;
        atArgAnnos=new HashMap<>(a.length);
        for(int ix = 0; ix < a.length; ix++)
            atArgAnnos.put(param[ix], a[ix]);
    }
    else throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "type variables, wildcard or arrays are not supported");
    raw.asSubclass(target);// throws if not assignable
    for(AnnotatedType aift: target.isInterface()? raw.getAnnotatedInterfaces():
                            new AnnotatedType[]{raw.getAnnotatedSuperclass()}) {
        Type ift=aift.getType();
        if(ift==target) return new Annotation[typeParameters.length][0]; // raw
        else {
            AnnotatedParameterizedType ifpt = (AnnotatedParameterizedType)aift;
            if(((ParameterizedType)ifpt.getType()).getRawType()!=target) continue;
            return Arrays.stream(ifpt.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments())
                  .map(ta -> atArgAnnos.getOrDefault(ta.getType(), ta.getAnnotations()))
                  .toArray(Annotation[][]::new);
        }
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
        t.getTypeName()+" does not (directly) extend or implement "+target);
}
```

It also doesn’t handle type variables, wildcard types or arrays; it’s already quite complicated. But it handle the example of your question and also the case that either or both of `Map`’s type parameters doen’t appear in the declaration of the field’s type, e.g.

```
interface AnotherExample<ID, KEY> extends Map<KEY, @Size(min=100) String> {
    ID getId();
}
```

and

```
AnotherExample<String, @Size(min=42) String> field;
```

It also works when having a type declaration like `interface I<X> extends Map<X,X> {}` and a field declaration `I<@Size(min=10) String> field;`, so the annotation applies to both, key and value type.

The returned annotation correspond to the type parameters of the specified type; it can be used like:

```
System.out.print(field.getName()+"\t");
Annotation[][] a=getActualAnnotations(field.getAnnotatedType(), Map.class);
System.out.println("key: "+Arrays.toString(a[0])+", value: "+Arrays.toString(a[1]));
```